# UART without using the same clock

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, uart

I am using the [C027 development board](http://developer.mbed.org/platforms/u-blox-C027/) for prototyping an application and I was wondering it it was possible to use the Tx and Rx pins of the GSM module (available on the [pinout of the board](http://developer.mbed.org/platforms/u-blox-C027/) as P0_15 and P0_16) to communicate with another microcontroller on another board (like the MSP430 Launchpad).

I think that it is not possible as both ends have to share the same clock in order to be synchronized but I therefore do not understand why they put these pins on the pinout.

Is it possible in my situation to communicate by UART without having the same physical clock connected to the two components ?

Comment: Do you know what the A stands for in UART?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Communicating through UART does not require your systems to have synchronized clocks.

As Majenko pointed out, the A in USART is Asynchronous.

So long as you have the correct BAUD rate, and have your data bits, parity and stop bits setup to match both systems, you will be able to communicate.